# How to make silky smooth chocolate like galaxy bar or dairy milk bar?

Tags: chocolate

How to make silky smooth chocolate like galaxy bar or dairy milk bar from chocolate compound?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this must be a duplicate, but I couldn't turn up anything in search. If somebody else finds an appropriate duplicate target, please VTC.

Comment: @rumtscho like [this one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66936/making-dark-chocolate-at-home/66948#66948)?

Comment: @rumtscho perhaps this https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/87424/how-to-correctly-make-chocolate-bars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making dark chocolate at home](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/66936/making-dark-chocolate-at-home)

Answer (score 5):

Very short answer: you can't.

Making smooth chocolate bars is an industrial process, not replicable in the home, at least not with reasonable amounts of effort and money. You need specialized know-how, equipment, and access to the proper raw materials.

Also, compound chocolate is not suited for making chocolate bars. It is a different end product, meant to be used as a cheaper and easier-to-melt alternative to proper chocolate bars, it is not a raw material for chocolate bars.